# Django url adding order parameter

Tags: django

I have urls like:

```
url(r'^utilisateurs/$', view = list_users, name='list_users'),
url(r'^utilisateurs/(?P<userType>[\w-]+)/$', view = list_users, name='list_users_by_type'),
url(r'^utilisateurs/order_by/(?P<orderBy>[\w-]+)/$', view = list_users, name='list_users_order_by'),
url(r'^utilisateurs/(?P<userType>[\w-]+)/order_by/(?P<orderBy>[\w-]+)/$', view = list_users, name='list_users_by_type_order_by'),
```

I am trying to put a order_by tab in my template like below:

```
<ul id='menu-order-by'>
            <li><a href='{{ request.get_full_path }}order_by/title/'>Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see i am adding order_by parameter manually because the list can already be filtered . And the order_by menu items must order according to the current filtered list.

Can there be a better way to accomplist this task?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need some thing like {% url %} tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url
There you can provide parameters into this tag, like {% url 'list_users_order_by' [[WHATEVER YOU PASS]] %}. If in WHATEVER YOU PASS you provide 'title', it's will be what you need.

Comment: I tried the ? query parameters with request.sessions but will try your advice too thanks. For now  I have changed the links hrefs to --> {{ request.path }}?order=title